# undefined method `load_missing_constant' for module `ActiveSupport::Dependencies'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system, browsercms

I have a problem when I create new project using BrowserCMS,
so i just installed the gem

```
$ gem install browsercms
```

and when i create new project

```
$ bcms demo project_name
```

after bundle complete i got this error

```
rake  cms:install:migrations
rake aborted!
undefined method `load_missing_constant' for module `ActiveSupport::Dependencies'(NameError)
```

so what's the reason of this error?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? What version of BrowserCMS?

Comment: @Ryan I'm Using Rails 3.2.2 and Version of Rails which used by Latest version of BrowserCMS is 3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by some old files still existing in BrowserCMS, and was fixed [in a later version](https://github.com/browsermedia/browsercms/issues/470)